# How to open a link from one UIWebView to another UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiscrollview

I'm building an iOS app.
I have HTML content in a `UIWebView` with hyperlinks, and I'm unable to open a link to another `UIWebView`.
I used `UIWebView` as a subview of `ViewController`. Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    switch (navigationType) {
        case UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked: { //this is when a user tap is detected
            //write the handling code here.
            isWebViewLoaded = false; //set this to false only if you open another view  controller.
            return NO; //prevent tapped URL from loading inside the UIWebView.
        }

        // some other typical parameters within a UIWebView. Use what is needed
        case UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted: return YES;
        case UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload: return YES;

        //for all other cases, including UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther called when UIWebView is loading for the first time
        default: {
            if (!isWebViewLoaded) { 
                isWebViewLoaded = true; 
                return YES; 
            }
            else 
                return NO;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying you want to open a link in a separate UIWebView?

Comment: Seems your code is from : http://cloudfields.net/blog/uiwebview-link-interceptor/   , anyway once you intercept why can't you simply open a new uiwebview with the trapped URL ? - you have all the info

Comment: If you explain why you need to do this we will be able to help you better.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks!,because of new to iOS development,i am not getting how can i used this code to meet my requirements.

Comment: Above code is not working,links are clickable but there is not any event,i want when a user click on link and it is open in a new UIWebView with back button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to segue to a new controller with a web view, and pass the request to it. So something like this in your first case,

```
 case UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked: { //this is when a user tap is detected
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Next" sender:request];
            isWebViewLoaded = false; //set this to false only if you open another view  controller.
            return NO; //prevent tapped URL from loading inside the UIWebView.
        }
```

Notice that the sender argument in performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: is the request returned by the delegate method. Pass this request to a property in the view controller you're segueing to,

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSURLRequest *)sender {
    NextViewController *next = segue.destinationViewController;
    next.request = sender;
}
```

Finally, use that request to load the web view in NextViewController.

Comment: thanks! rdelmar,I have applied your code but it shows error:
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSURLRequest *)sender {
    UIWebView *next = segue.destinationViewController;
    next.request = sender;  //error:Assignment to readonly property
}

Comment: @Daljeet, This line is wrong, and not what I have in my answer --"UIWebView *next = segue.destinationViewController; " "next" is supposed to be a view controller with a web view in its view, not a UIWebView.

Comment: @rdekmar,I applied UIViewController as well but same error occurs. UIViewController *next = segue.destinationViewController;          next.request = sender; //error:Assignment to readonly property

Comment: @Daljeet, update your question with an edit to show the code you are now using. You shouldn't be using UIViewController either (which I also don't have in my answer -- please read it carefully). You need to have a subclass of UIViewController so you can add a property called "request" to its .h file.